# How do I pull data from a HTML table, specifically <td id="word">, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table that will be populated with data and I need to be able to pull data from specific cells using the cell ID. I have tried using `document.getElementById("idName").value` but I have now come to understand that the `.value` is only used with `<input>` tags. I need the JavaScript code to get the data from the `<td>` tag, using the ID, and not by hard coding in the information that is in the table as the information will change in that cell.

EDIT: Here is the JavaScript code
'

```
var RNNo5a = document.getElementById("RN5.5").innerText;
var RNNo5 = document.getElementById("RbR4.4").innerHTML;
var RNN04a = document.getElementById("RN6.4").innerHTML;
//var test;
//if (RNNo5a == RNNo5) {test = RNN04a;}
alert(RNNo5a);
```

`

The table is filled out by another JavaScript code... could that be the source of my problem?

Comment: .html() or .text() aren't working for you? .value/.val() is for form fields.

Comment: `document.getElementById("idName").innerText`

Comment: @MarcB I've tried .innerHTML and .innerText and neither work. How exactly would I use .html() or .text()? Would I type document.html("idName")?

Comment: doesn't work how? you get nothing? node isn't found?  and .text/.html are jquery, so if you don't have that loaded, you'll need .innerText/.innerHTML

Comment: As far as you are using a correct id for the cell it should work fine. How do you check the value of `a` after `var a = document.getElementById("idName").innerText` ?

Comment: The code for it is as follows `var a = document.getElementById("idName").innerText;` then `document.getElementById("idName2").innerHTML = a;` . The cell that the code is entering the data into is blank, while before it would state undefined (this is how I am checking the code).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getElementsById("IdName").innerHTML`

The `innerHTML` property sets or returns the `HTML` content (inner HTML) of an element.

You can read more on `innerHTML` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

**EDIT** RE OP's comment - It works in the below example.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;

alert(x);
```

```html
<p id="test">Hello, World!</p>
```

Comment: I've tried that and .innerText and they did not work. My current code reads `var a = document.getElementById("idName").innerHTML;`

Comment: @JoeC see the above snippet. It works here.
Maybe you could add your code to your question so we can see exactly what's going on

Comment: I have edited my original post with the code. I think that I have possibly located my issue; however I am not sure.